# My desktop is restarted automatically

Tags: windows-xp, motherboard, reboot, overheating

I have been using my PC for the last 6 years, but now suddenly it keeps restarting and then  it stops detecting my hard drive. When I switch on my PC next day, it will detect the hard drive again and run smoothly for some period of time and same problem repeats again & again

I have replaced my hard drive with an other other one, but the same problem happens again.
I have applied heat sink gel, but it has no effect.

Comment: any error messages in event viewer?

Comment: 6 years you say? In those 6 years did you ever change the PSU? You know the cheap to mid PSUs only last up to 3 years or so after which they can exhibit odd behaviors like system restarts.

Comment: I am also thinking same to change the PSU. I try other PSU and let you know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue and for me, it was a faulting hard drive. I think you need to test yours. 
I suggest you download a SMART tool like [Acronis (free)](http://www.acronis.co.uk/homecomputing/products/drive-monitor/) and see the report of your hard drive.

Regardless of what you do, BACK IT UP NOW!